# Apache Cassandra integration with RabbitMQ

Tags: cassandra, rabbitmq, message-queue, mqtt

I want to use MQTT as a protocol communication with RabbitMQ Message Broker, but from rabbitmq website I found this paragraph:

> These implementations are suitable for development but sometimes won't be for production needs. MQTT 3.1 specification does not define consistency or replication requirements for retained message stores, therefore RabbitMQ allows for custom ones to meet the consistency and availability needs of a particular environment. For example, stores based on Riak and Cassandra would be suitable for most production environments as those data stores provide tunable consistency.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/mqtt.html

So, from this paragraph, I should to use Cassandra as a database for RabbitMQ, but I didn't find anything about integration Cassandra as a database for rabbitmq.

can you help me by giving me something to make it possible.

NB:I'm newbie in RabbitMQ.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Until now, RabbitMQ doesn't support this feature.
so, it's not possible to use another database instead of Mnseia database

Comment: The question is: why should a messaging queue have a direct connection to a database? I would not consider that a feature.

Answer (score 1):

The paragraph refers specifically to "retained messages" part of MQTT spec, as in, the messages you want to keep for a long time. Like a "last know configuration", that you may want to apply to any MQTT subscriber, regardless whether or not it has been online and subscribed at the moment the message is published.

It's a very particular situation and unless you need that feature you don't have to worry about using RabbitMQ as MQTT broker. For regular messages built-in RabbitMQ replication options are perfectly suitable and production-ready.

Comment: in fact , I will need this feature, but I still can't configure Cassandra as a database instead of mensia (default database of rabbitmq)

Comment: Mnesia is used as backend for rabbitmq to persist queues and settings, there is no reason to exchange that to Cassandra.